# Why do python .pyc files contain the absolute path of their source code?

Tags: python

Why do python `.pyc` files contain the absolute path of their source code, instead of a relative path or something else?

A typical `__init__.pyc` from Python 2.7 on Ubuntu:

`\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdOc@sddlTdS(i\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd(t*N(tdbapi2(((s&/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py<module>s`

Comment: I just tested with Python 2.7 on Linux and the .pyc file doesn't contain an absolute path.

Comment: Then provide the exact steps you followed to create the pyc and see that it contains an absolute path, in a way that anyone can reproduce. What I did was create an empty `a.py` file, import it from the interactive prompt, and then run `strings a.pyc`.

Comment: @interjay In this case it doesn't happen, but if you `import` from another folder, you'll probably see the full path (just tried).

Comment: What drew you to this detail? Is there a problem you're having because of it?

Comment: I heard that Python might not be able to find the source file for tracebacks if the source and .pyc was moved after compilation.

Comment: pyc files assume their source is in the same directory that they themselves are in and therefore can't and don't provide meaningful tracebacks (other that the type of error, that is) when that's not the case. This is easily verified with a simple test case. So the answer is, they don't store their source path in any form.

Comment: @martineau Not necessarily true, see [PEP-3147](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/).

Comment: @poke: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that (or that the OP was talking about `import`ing a package and was using Py 3.2).

Comment: The reason that a pyc may contain a relative path is probably that the py file was imported with a relative path itself.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, trying to achieve reproducible builds with PyInstaller is what drew me to this question.  I DO see file paths for the computer that built the final dist from PyInstaller in the .pyc.  This is on Windows 10 with Python 3.8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To give the information in tracebacks.  See for instance http://docs.python.org/library/compileall#cmdoption-compileall-d

Comment: Note that Éric's link leads to the "-d" option, which can be used to get relative paths into .pyc files instead of the usual absolute path.

Comment: What would happen if these files are moved to another machine and the paths don't match anymore?

Comment: The information reported in some tracebacks would be wrong.